# uvm register write is stuck and never return

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I have some block of register along with corresponding register adaptor setup to translate into some bus protocol.

When I called the `write` method to one of my register, I could see the transaction going on, and `driver` complete its job, but `write` is stuck somewhere.

Please see excerpt of `driver` and `sequence` below:

```
// ...uvm driver
forever begin
  seq_item_port.get_next_item(req);
  $display("DEBUG A");
  // ... do transaction
  seq_item_port.item_done();
  $display("DEBUG B");
end

// ... sequence
$display("START WRITE");
my_reg_block.my_reg1.write(
$display("DONE WRITE");
```

The result:

```
START WRITE
DEBUG A
DEBUG B
```

and then simulation stuck there - I never see `DONE WRITE`.

I am quite sure all the `connect`, `set_sequencer` has been made properly - otherwise my driver shouldn't see transaction in the first place. And this is pretty simple test - only doing that `write`.

Any idea why it is stuck in register `write` method eventhough the `driver` seems to have completed the transaction? I probably missed something.

Comment: Can you add some more details about your sequence and the `write` method inside it?

Comment: uvm verbosity of UVM_HIGH /UVM_DEBUG could be useful . It will print out additional information from the reg model like where in the write task it is . It can give a clue as to what's happening .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `uvm_reg_map::do_bus_write(...)` there's the following code snippet that handles the bus request for a register access:

```
  bus_req.set_sequencer(sequencer);
  rw.parent.start_item(bus_req,rw.prior);

  if (rw.parent != null && i == 0)
    rw.parent.mid_do(rw);

  rw.parent.finish_item(bus_req);
  bus_req.end_event.wait_on();
```

Notice the `end_event.wait_on()`. This event is normally triggered on a sequence item by the sequencer, once `item_done()` was called and `finish_item()` returns:

```
`ifndef UVM_DISABLE_AUTO_ITEM_RECORDING
sequencer.end_tr(item);
`endif
```

It's possible to turn this off using the define, which is what I guess is happening in your case.

Comment: exactly due to the define, great guess